# R — plotrix:pie3D — Smallest slices disappear

Tags: r, pie-chart, plotrix

I'm having troubles with creating nice looking pie charts in R using `plotrix:pie3D`. In my datasets I have two values that each represent `~1%` of the total, but when I make pie charts only one of the smallest slices are shown. I've tried reordering the slices to with no success, still the smallest one disappears. I hope this example will illustrate what I mean:

```
lbs <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G")
test1 <- c(7,6,77,224,114,50,352)
test2 <- c(6,7,77,224,114,50,352)
pie3D(test1,labels = lbs, border = F,col = rainbow(n=7,s=0.6,v=0.75),explode=0.2)
pie3D(test2,labels = lbs, border = F,col = rainbow(n=7,s=0.6,v=0.75),explode=0.2)
```

[image: test1_pie3D] - Slice B disappears
[image: test2_pie3D]  - Slice A disappears

If I make a regular pie chart using `pie()` both slices show up, but I would like to make the nicer looking pie chart with `plotrix`. Any ideas on how to solve this issue? 
(If I change the smallest value to the same as the second smallest, then both slices show up and have a suitable size, but that feels like cutting corners and not solving the real issue.)